# Angular5 PDF Generation from HTML or JSON

Tags: spring, angular5

I am working with angular5 app with backend in spring java , I need to create PDF (exam form preview pdf) , can you please suggest me on which side is preferable (client or server) ? if on client then suggest me any ng5 package .

Answer (score 0):

On server side. There are a lot of examples how to create pdf in java. Simply google it. Here are few of them. 
[Spring MVC - Generate PDF Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_pdf.htm) 
[Generate PDF Using Spring Framework](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/generate-pdf-using-spring-framework) 
[Creating PDF Files in Java](http://www.baeldung.com/java-pdf-creation)